# Reaction to Scratching Noise

Tags: phrases

I need a word or phrase to describe the sensation people experience when they hear nails scratching on a chalkboard.  I don't want to describe the *noise* , just the *sensation.*

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Thanks for the reference to the previous post........How do I mark this Question "Answered"??

Comment: Short answer: you can't. You cannot even delete your question because it has received two answers. You could award somebody's post and that might discourage new answers from being suggested. I think only a moderator can close this question now. Try flagging it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA   Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can describe it about the same way you did: *like nails on a chalkboard*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common terms for that include:

- Sets (my) teeth on edge
- Makes (my) skin crawl
- Makes (my) hair stand on end

Answer (score 2):

> It makes teeth grind (or *hurt*)

*That screeching noise [**makes my teeth hurt**](http://m.ehealthforum.com/health/can-t-touch-cloth-with-wet-hands-t143541_20.html).*